# Call Einstein Flow Strategy Builder from Apex

Tags: einstein-recommendations, einstein-next-best-action

I have a requirement where I need to call recommendation strategy flow (for nba) from apex. I was wondering if anyone has tried calling recommendation strategy flow template from apex ?